# saving session data once authenticated .net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, session

So I'm building a web application in .NET using c#, MVC and sqlexpress. I want users to be able to login and depending on what group they belong to, see some part of an UI.

I have created the tables for groups and users in my database, created models from those tables using ADO.NET wizard for model creation.

I have added a controller that has methods for checking if a user exists, and if his password is correct. My question is how to store the information that the user is authenticated the "©correct" way?

At the moment, i just create a new object in the session variable that is made available by `System.Web.Mvc.Controller`. I have made a flag object `Session["Authenticated"] = true` and created another object that holds the information (username, group affiliation etc...) as `Session["User"]`.

I have stumbled upon articles that describe implementing your own membership provider ([here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366730%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f1kyba5e%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)) but I feel that I would need to break my existing classes for password security and account control in order to implement them inside of the custom membership provider.

Is the custom membership provider implementation necessary or is the data saved in the session good enough?

Comment: The idea of a custom membership provider is to use the existing Membership Provider with your own data scheme. You can store membership/roles in cookies and retrieve it from there. I would recommend not to use session variables.

Answer (score 0):

A better way if you don't want to go down the membership provider route would be to look into forms authentication (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xdt4thhy(v=vs.100).aspx).

Comment: from what I got from that code, `FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(UserEmail.Text, Persist.Checked)` saves the user info somewhere, but then i still have no way of saving what group he belongs to.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly save Roles and Permissions regarding user and write custom Action filter in which check If User have permission for access the controller method if yes then go as its going if not then generate exception and response message.

> When User Login then also Get Current User Roles and Permissions and save it on Session in custom filters or on your buttons and tabs check from Session User have permission or not if User have permission then show the tab otherwise hide it. 
>   Here is link for Example
>   [Action Filters](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/hands-on-labs/aspnet-mvc-4-custom-action-filters)
>   [Filters Example Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/426766/Custom-Filters-in-MVC-Authorization-Action-Result)

Answer (score 0):

one of the most easy way to implement authentication and authorization in an ASP.NET MVC project is to use the inbuild Forms Authentication module. When you create a new ASP.NET MVC project, it already incorporates all that is necessary to get you started with the Forms Auth.

All it will do is to create certain tables (5), and you never have to worry or track them every in your code. Its all very simple. You can always map the users created by ASP.NET MVC membership provider to your very own `UserMaster` table.

And next, all you have to do is to mark your ActionMethod or your Controller or in global.asax the `[Authorize]` attribute, and you are all set.

Code will be as simple as :

for login:

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
{
     if (ModelState.IsValid && WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password, 
                                                persistCookie: model.RememberMe))
        {
            ///rest of the logic
        }
 }
```

also below are some userful functions which will come in handy:

```
if(WebSecurity.UserExists(username)){ /// ur logic }
//or
WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(username, password);
//or
System.Web.Security.Roles.AddUserToRole(username, UserRole);
```

and guess what, you don't have to worry abt setting some flag in some `HttpModule` or first always executing function to see if the session User exists or not, `[Authorize]` attribute takes care of that.

Mapping with custom `UserMaster`

```
if (ModelState.IsValid && WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password, 
                                           persistCookie: model.RememberMe))
{
    try
    {
         try
         {
             //below is my custom method IsValidUser with my own logic for 
             // valid user
             MembershipCore.IsValidUser(model.UserName);
             if (MembershipCore.isFirstTimeLogin(model.UserName))
             {
                    //Show License Screen in a window
                    return RedirectToAction("License");

              }
              //my custom method setting custom Session variables
              MembershipCore.SetLoggedInUser(model.UserName);
          }
      }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand the part when you say "You can always map the users created by ASP.NET MVC membership provider to your very own `UserMaster` table.", how would one go about doing that?

Comment: manually. Whenever you create a new user using the `WebSecurity` class, at the same time, after successful creating, add the user to your UserMaster table with all those fields, firstLogin, Activated, LastLogin and so on. Whenever user comes to login, after `WebSecurity.Login`, also verify UserMaster fields for the User. And also, make the two manual processes atomic i.e. if any one of them fails, make the other fail too.

Comment: So your saying ta have a separate set of tables that `WebSecurity` uses and just ghost the info from those tables to my tables, and then do twin checks, one via the out of the box methods, and then another for my database. seems kind of roundabout to me, i feel like there must be an easier way without so much redundancy.